# Anyone know what position: -ms-page; does in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Anyone know what

```
position: -ms-page
```

does?

So far I haven't been able to find any documentation on it, but somehow it fixed an IE specific z-index problem I was having when I added it with position relative. i.e.

```
position: relative;
position: -ms-page;
```

Found it by cycling through posible positions in IE11 dev tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531140(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Internet Explorer 10. Object is positioned relative to the nearest initial containing block. This may be the viewport or a content container such as an iframe. The positioning properties are used to position the element relative to the boundaries of the viewport area. For more information, see Section 6.4 "Page positioning" of the "W3C CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3" specification.

"-ms-page" is equivalent to "page".

Comment: Good catch, I totally went to that page multiple times and never realized "page" was the same as "-ms-page".